# Como hacer cambios en el JPanel dependiendo de qué JRadiButton seleccione

Tags: java

Muy buenas, quería pediros ayuda para un problema del que no encuentro nada en internet.

Estoy programando con interifcies gráficas en Java y quería hacer una interficie con diferentes opciones (JRadioButton) y que dependiendo de esta elección el JFrame me salga diferentes componentes.

Mi caso:

Estoy haciendo un programa que manipula una pila. Y tengo 3 opciones: Poner (algo en la pila), Quitar, Ver contenido.

Lo que yo quiero hacer es elegir la opcion "Poner", en el JPanel me salga una caja de texto. Si elijo la opción "Quitar" me salga un String en un JTextField del objeto que ha quitado. Y si elijo la opcion "Ver contenido" en un JtextArea me enseñe todo el contenido de la pila.

Todas las opciones las tengo implementadas, pero solo necesito saber como puedo hacer para que, pulsando diferentes opciones, me salgan unos complementos o otros.

Comment: Puedes jugar con la propiedad de visibilidad de los componentes y ponerlos a true or false dependiendo del evento del conjunto de RadioButtons

Comment: @ValentínSánchezBoto Hola, lo que he estado jugando con las creaciones del JPanel con el fin de crear uno encima del Principal y luego borrarlo al terminar la operación. Es una buena solución?

Comment: Eso creo que consume mas recursos que simplemente tener un componente colocado y quitarle o ponerle la visibilidad cuando lo necesites usar.

Comment: Deberías usar los métodos de visibilidad que ofrece java .setEnable(boolean), con esto dependiendo de lo que selecciones visualizas o no, el componente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas escuchar a los componentes que el usuario puede seleccionar. Por ejemplo:

```
JRadioButton botonPoner = new JRadioButton();
botonPoner.setActionCommand("poner");
JRadioButton botonQuitar = new JRadioButton();
botonQuitar.setActionCommand("quitar");
JRadioButton botonVerContenido = new JRadioButton();
botonVerContenido.setActionCommand("ver contenido");
```

Luego creas un objeto que escuche a los botones:

```
protected class ManejadorDeEventos implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evento) {
        switch(evento.getActionCommand()) {
          case "poner" :
              //aqui pones tu implementación que pone
              break;
          case "quitar" :
              //aquí implementas para quitar
              break;
          case "ver contenido":
              //aquí muestras contenido
              break;
        }
}
```

Luego ligas los botones para que sean escuchados por tu manejador de eventos.

```
 ManejadorDeEventos manejador = new ManejadorDeEVentos();
 botonPoner.addActionListener(manejador);
 botonQuitar.addActionListener(mandejador);
 botonVerContenido.addActionListener(manejador);
```

Tu manejador de eventos ya está escuchando los botones y puede tomar acción según el seleccionado.

Comment: Hola @AlbertoLopez , muchas gracias por tu respuesta. He estado intentando hacer lo mismo que usted me ha propuesto pero solo con la diferencia de que ponia un JPanel encima del otro. Y tampoco ligaba los botones. ¡Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!